# Send a SOME/IP message with CANoe and the vector box between two ECU already connected

Tags: vector, canoe, vsomeip

I'm working on a rack where I have several ECU connected.
I want to test if my Ecu2 is reacting well when it is receiving a specific message from my ECU1.
I used the CANoe to simulate the ECU1 and on the CAPL send the desired signal. But I was getting issue because my simulated node and ECU1 had the same id. So I have modified the IP of the simulated in the database.
When I send my signal, I get an invalid message because the subscription is fighting between the simulated node and the ECU1. I can see a message "the endpoint change old: "ECU1 ip", new "simulated node". And I can get the expected behavior when I'm rebooting the ECU1. But this is aleatory.

Is there a way to make think to the ECU2 that the message from the vector box came from the ECU1?
Many thanks!

I tried to make it run with the same IP address but the simulated node is sending a lot of signal and this create me an IP conflict.